# Confusions about Divisors of F on Elliptic Curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, rational-functions, divisors-algebraic-geometry

In a rational function the divisors is defined as

$$div(f) = \sum e_i[a_i] - f_i[b_i]$$ for function
$$f = \frac{(x-a_i)^e}{(x-b_i)^f}$$

Hence it is the zeros of the numerator and the denominator.

For divisors on f defined on elliptic curve E with point P

$$div_{P\in E}(f) = \sum n_p[P]$$ Where n_p is the order of point P. Here is point P

1. the intersection of f and E or
2. zeros of f that also lie on E?

I've worked through multiple textbooks/lecture notes and can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: The *zero/pole, local ring, uniformizer, discrete valuation* intuition is easier on the complex torus side than on the complex elliptic curve side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Divisor on Elliptic Curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3189147/divisor-on-elliptic-curve)

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55342/i-cannot-understand-the-concept-of-a-divisor-for-an-elliptic-curve